# How to add strip after split in lambda?

Tags: python, lambda

How can strip the key value after a split inside of lambda ?

```
   l = ["   key1  :      value1  ", "   key2  :      value2 ", "  key3 "]
   d = {}
   d = dict(map(lambda s : s.split(':'), l))
   print d

   # print d['key2'] should work
```

The result has spaces :

```
[['   key1  ', '      value1  '], ['   key2  ', '      value2 '], ['  key3 ']]
```

Comment: Can't you call `strip` before `split`ting?

Comment: Why do you initialize `d` as `{}`? Are you aware that `map` does _not_ produce a "map" in the sense of a Java `Map` or Python `dict`?

Comment: If you want a `dict`, you could pass the results to the `dict` function, i.e. `dict(map(...))` or dict([[...]...])`, but note that there is no value to `key3`

Answer (score 1):

You can strip each element after splitting:

```
map(lambda s: [p.strip() for p in s.split(':')], l)
```

Demo

```
>>> l = ["   key1  :      value1  ", "   key2  :      value2 ", "  key3 "]
>>> map(lambda s: [p.strip() for p in s.split(':')], l)
[['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3']]
```

I used a list comprehension rather than a `map()` call there; it's a little easier on the eye.

You can make the whole thing a nested list comprehension too:

```
[[p.strip() for p in s.split(':')] for s in l]
```

Now, if you wanted to produce a dictionary, you'll have to filter out any entry that is not a key-value pair:

```
dict((p.strip() for p in s.split(':')) for s in l if ':' in s)
```

Comment: I want after the split

Comment: @Victor: but your input examples don't suffer from whitespace around the `:`. You'll get *exactly the output you need* with this.

Comment: I like the second one where  you used p, but i still get error : NameError: global name 'split' is not defined

Comment: cool worked : d= map(lambda p: [p.strip() for p in p.split(':')], l)

Comment: Why not go full list-comp? `[[p.strip() for p in s.split(':')] for s in l]`

Comment: huh . print d['key2'] gives TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @Victor `map()` returns a list, not a dict

Comment: @MartijnPieters dict(map(lambda p: [p.strip() for p in p.split(':')], rlist)) works only problem is if there is an element that is not a key:value it throws exception

Comment: @Victor yes, you always must produce two elements; if your input doesn't have a value or a key then you need to filter those out. Add `if ':' in s` to the end of the list comprehension for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to create a `dict` from that list. Note than [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), while similar in name to a Java `Map`, does not produce a `dict`. Instead, you can feed the result of the `map` or list comprehension into the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) builtin function. Note, however, that there is no value for `key3`, so you might have to filter the elements before.

```
>>> l = ["   key1  :      value1  ", "   key2  :      value2 ", "  key3 "]
>>> pairs = [[p.strip() for p in s.split(':')] for s in l]
>>> dict(p for p in pairs if len(p) == 2)
{'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

Or use [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> triplets = [[p.strip() for p in s.partition(":")] for s in l]
>>> dict((p[0], p[2]) for p in triplets)
{'key3': '', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```

You could also use a dict comprehension, and optionally provide a default for missing values.

```
>>> {head: tail or "default" for head, _, tail in triplets}
{'key3': 'default', 'key2': 'value2', 'key1': 'value1'}
```